# How to set range for int with SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer

How to limit an int column to allow only values within a specific range using the SSMS designer?

Comment: Please provide sample data and a clear explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Is your question how to limit an int column to allow only values within a specific range using the SSMS designer?

Comment: Yes Please help